# How to show custom options in layer navigation

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, custom-options, layered-navigation, filter

Some of my products have custom options for size/color/etc. I'd like to allow users to filter by these like they can filter by regular attributes.

The site I'm working on is here: http://www.electravapor.com/accessories.html

I essentially want a list of all possible colors under the "SHOP BY" block, allowing users to filter the same as they can with price.

Answer (score 0):

You custom options will fall under layer navigation in your categories. You can filter by any of those items.

Make sure you list your category as an anchor and your attribute as filterable. (with or without results)

Comment: The category has Is Anchor set to Yes, but are you saying that a product's custom options are associated with an attribute? I don't see where.

Sorry if my question is unclear, I'm still very new to magento. Thanks in advance.

Comment: brentwpeterson is talking about custom *attributes*, not custom options, as you required.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to filter by custom options without building an extension for it. Your best bet will be to use custom attributes instead which can be used for filtering and layered navigation.